# Serilog setup in common class library - ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have several ASP.NET Core 2 application for which I want to setup Serilog with various Sinks.
In order to not have to setup Serilog in every project, I have a separate class **BaseProgram** in a separate class library from which my other **Program** classes inherit (I've omitted some code for brivety)

```
public abstract class BaseProgram
{
    public static int MainWrapper(Action run)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
            run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
 }
```

And my Program class looks like:

```
public class Program : BaseProgram
{
    public static void Main(string args[])
    {
        MainWrapper(() => BuildWebHost(args).Run());
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that if I add a Serilog Sink in the Common library only (Rolling File Appender) and add the configuration for it in appsettings.json, the Sink isn't loaded.

On the other hand, if I add the Rolling File Appender to the ASP.NET Core project (and change nothing else), everything works as expected.
I've noticed that in the first case, the assemblies Serilog.Sinks.File and Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile aren't copied to the bin folder of the ASP.NET Core application. I've forced the loading of those assemblies, but it still doesn't work.

For now I've setup the Rolling File appender programatically in the class library and it works fine. I can also add extra Sinks in the ASP.NET Core application and they still work.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix this?